# BigQuery SQL: Given string input. how to confirm it is a valid date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working on filter the records that don't have valid dates associated with them.
The expectant is a string of format `yyyymmddhhmmss` . How can I validate that the string is actually a valid date?
For example the input string could be: `202101....##` (invalid literals)

Answer (score 1):

Would a filter like ...

```
WHERE SAFE_CAST (datestring AS DATE) IS NOT NULL
```

serve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `safe.parse_datetime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', col_string) as col_datetime` - if `col_string` represents valid datetime - it will output that valid datetime, otherwise - null, as in dummy example below

```
with your_table as (
  select '20211215031521' col_string union all 
  select '20211215031521Y' union all 
  select '202112150H1521' 
)
select col_string, 
  safe.parse_datetime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', col_string) as col_datetime
from your_table
```

with output

[image]